# WebClient.DownloadFile doesn't work

Tags: c#, webclient

I am trying to download a file from my server, and I do this:

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(@"C:\Files\project\result.xlsx", "download.xlsx");
```

and the exception says this:

```
2015-01-27 13:08:13,686 [55] ERROR GeneralLogger - System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\download.xlsx' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)
   at EmailTemplates.Classes.ExcelUtil.CreateNewExcelFile(String variables) in
```

I never used the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\download.xlsx` probably is the default or something like that. 
I want to dowlonad the file as when you click in download, on any page (i do this because i create the file in the same function)

Thanks.

Comment: You first argument should be the URL of the remote file you wish to download. The second is to local path where to save it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you misunderstood what `DownloadFile` does. It does not *send* a file to clients of your web app. It downloads a file *from* a server. Since you did not specify any URL I assume that's your mistake.

Research how to send a file as the response to an HTTP request. I'd search for "ASP.NET download file".